# How to call @BeforeSuite after instantiation of webdriver in Arquillian

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jboss-arquillian, arquillian-drone

I am trying to use @BeforeSuite after instantiation of webdriver in Arquillian

I am just give a example below

```
@RunAsClient
public class GoogleTest extends Arquillian {

    @Drone
    private WebDriver driver;

    @ArquillianResource
    private URL contextRoot;

    @Page
    Google googlePage;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void init() {
        driver.get(contextRoot.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void googleSearchTest() {
        System.out.println(contextRoot);
        googlePage.searchFor("Arquillian Graphene");
    }
}
```

But it is getting null pointer exception because driver not instantiate. So My question is how to call my @BeforeSuite after Arquillian defined @BeforeSuite.

I don't want to do the webdriver instantiation part, I prefer it should be handled by Arquillian @Drone annotation and I will execute my own @BeforeSuite after that.

Comment: `@BeforeSuite` annotation is, by its own definition, the FIRST thing to be performed before ANYTHING else in a test suite.  If you need to have the driver instantiated for that method, then you need to instantiate the driver IN that method.

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver life cycle is controlled by Arquillian Drone. You do not have to instantiate it!

You should not access `WebDriver` in the `BeforeSuite` as it would not have been initialized by Arquillian by that time. Actually it does after that. So, this is a good place if you want to override any of your `arquillian.xml` settings programmatically.

If you want to do some setup using webdriver like login etc, You can do that in the test itself or `BeforeTest`. `BeforeSuite` is not a good place for launching a URL

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I understand I already do that but I try to implement this way, so I ask this question. I try to break the constrains of Arquillian.

Comment: I need to use BeforeMethod